# How to filter Exact match string using dplyr

Tags: r

I have datatable datatmp

```
    datatmp
        Code         Desc
       Z00.1 Description1
         Z00 Description2
         Z38 Description3
       Z38.0 Description4
       Z38.1 Description5
```

Try to filter only Z38 code using

```
datatmp %>% dplyr::filter(str_detect(Code,'Z38'))
```

But get the below result which incl. Z38.0 and Z38.1

```
   Code         Desc
    Z38 Description3
  Z38.0 Description4
  Z38.1 Description5
```

Also tried with  `datatmp %>% dplyr::filter(grepl('Z38',Code,fixed = TRUE))`  gives sample output.

Note: The above example I mentioned only one value i.e. Z38 in the filter condition , actually these values are dynamic. Example Z38 , Z00

Please suggest to find exact match only.

Comment: how about: `datatmp %>% dplyr::filter(Code == 'Z38')`

Comment: If you just want "Z38": `datatmp %>% filter(Code =="Z38") `

If you want to filter based on multiple values: `datatmp %>% filter(Code %in% c("Z38","Z00"))`

Comment: the filtering condition to be framed dynamically

Comment: You mean
`cond <- "Z38"`
`datatmp %>% filter(Code ==cond)` ?

Comment: yes, cond as selected please ref. this url for details [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41613296/shiny-using-selectizeinput-to-build-dynamic-data-output)

Answer (score 3):

You were close with your grepl filter. Change the code to:

```
datatmp %>% dplyr::filter(grepl("^Z38$", Code))
```

The ^ symbol denotes the start of the string (technically not necessary in this case) and the $ symbol denotes the end of the string, so Z38.0 would not match.