# Exact match on word in middle of string in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I referred this question ([How to filter Exact match string using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977763/how-to-filter-exact-match-string-using-dplyr)) but mine is slightly different as the word is not the start but can occur anywhere in the string. I want TRUE to be returned only for first one not the second & third

```
library(stringr)

vec <- c("this should be selected", "thisus should not be selected","not selected thisis too")
str_detect(vec,"this")
```

Current output

```
TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Expected output

```
TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a word boundary (`\\b`)

```
stringr::str_detect(vec,"\\bthis\\b")
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

In base R :

```
grepl('\\bthis\\b', vec)
```